# stopping parent background before child?? can it be done in css?

Tags: html, css, parent-child

im helping a friend edit an online profile.
we have complete access to and can edit the css but very limited access to and limited editing of the html of the profile.

we can add child divs to the profile and style them fine, but the parent css style is around them (like it normally is/should be).
is there a way of stopping the parent background styling at or before the children while still keeping the dynamic nature of styling (ie not using a background-image)

this is what we have so far https://jsfiddle.net/Lfccdjk6/2/... as you can see the parent and its 2 children each have a background, what we were/are hoping to do is stop the parent background before its children so that all 3 divs appear independent of each other

my HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
Interests &amp; Hobbies
</div>

<div class="container" id="meaning_life_container">
<span class="label" id="meaning_life_label">
Meaning of Life:
</span>
<span class="value" id="meaning_life_value">
blah blah               </span>
</div>

<div class="container" id="favorite_books_container">
<span class="label" id="favorite_books_label">
Favorite Books:
</span>

<span class="value" id="favorite_books_value">
blah blah,blah blah and blah blah             </span>
</div>
<div class="container" id="hobbies_container">
<span class="label" id="hobbies_label">
Hobbies:
</span>

<span class="value" id="hobbies_value">
camping                   </span>
</div>

<div class="container" id="know_me_container">
<span class="label" id="know_me_label">
Best Reason to Get to Know Me:
</span>

<span class="value" id="know_me_value">


<!---------------------------------->   
<!-- CAN EDIT ANYTHING BELOW HERE -->
<!----------------------------------> 

<div class="usercontent">
<div id="test">
<div class="heading"> test 1</div>

<div>
info 
</div>

random content
</div></div>
<div class="usercontent">
<div id="test2">
<div class="heading">test 2</div>

<div>
some random content 
</div>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah           

</div></div></span>

</div></div></div></div></body>'
```

my CSS:

```
body { background-color:pink;}

#profile_interests_content {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
display: table;
padding: 25px 25px 0;
width: auto;
margin: 0 80px;
}
.container {
display: block;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}
#profile_interests_content .label, #profile_interests_content .value {
display: block;
margin: 3px 0;
}
#profile_interests_content .value {
margin-left: 12px;
}
.label {
text-align: left;
min-width: 175px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#profile_interests_content #know_me_container #know_me_label {
display: none;
}
#test {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
width: auto;
margin: 20px -31px;
left: -6px;
position: relative;
}
.usercontent div {
padding: 20px;
}
#test2 {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
width: auto;
margin: 20px -31px;
left: -6px;
position: relative;
}
```

im complete stuck and before i redesign the whole profile i thought id ask to see if someone has any advice or can point me in different direction

cheers

Comment: You can [safely](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) remove all vendor prefixes for border-radius: `-prefix-border-radius` hasn't been necessary for a few years now ;)

Comment: oh cool thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use CSS Selectors that target the parent div and overwrite the background properties or you could create your own parent div inside of the main parent div.

```
<main div>
  <your sub parent div with your overwriting styles>
    <child div>
    </child div>
  <your sub parent div>
</main div>
```

Comment: hi... thanks for the quick replay.yeah i looked at creating my own divs but that would make it hard for the end user since the profile database wouldn't be accessible (we don't and cant get access to it) but it displays information to the divs already created

Comment: sorry for the double post.... ill have a look in to css selectors after lunch and see what i can come up with

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. this is bad practice but since you need it badly, you can use it. Read this:

https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

```
body{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: dont see how this would work... im only trying to remove the background from a part of a div not from the whole div or the body

Comment: `!important` overrides alll the css declaration with the same selector.